# Scatter plot in python with Groups

Tags: python, matplotlib

Below are three columns VMDensity, ServerswithCorrectable errors and VMReboots.

```
VMDensity   correctableCount    avgVMReboots
LowDensity  7   5
HighDensity 1   23
LowDensity  5   11
HighDensity 1   23
LowDensity  9   5
HighDensity 1   22
HighDensity 1   22
LowDensity  9   2
LowDensity  9   6
LowDensity  5   3
```

I tried the following but not sure how to create it by groups with different colors.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

plt.scatter(df.correctableCount, df.avgVMReboots)
```

Now, I need generate a `scatter plot` with the grouping by VMDensity. The low density VM's should be in one color and the high density in another one.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand you correctly you do not need to "group" the data: You want to plot *all* data points regardsless. You just want to *color* them differently. So try something like

```
plt.scatter(df.correctableCount, df.avgVMReboots, c=df.VMDensity)
```

You will need to map the `df.VMDensity` strings to numbers and/or play with [`scatter`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter)'s `cmap` parameter.

See this [example from matplotlib's gallery](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/shapes_and_collections/scatter.html).